# The same code fails in 2 differend projects. use of class template requires template argument list

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries

I am currently writing a basic maths library, inside my solution I have 2 projects, the only difference between them is that one was built using premake and the other one was just added to my solution. Both have the same code inside

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MathLib.h"
int main()
{
    MathLib::Matrix3x3<float> m;
    std::cout << m[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Matrix3x3 class looks like this:

```
template <class T>
    class Matrix3x3
    {
    public:
        Matrix3x3() : m_rows{} {}
        Matrix3x3(Static3Vector<T> v1, Static3Vector<T> v2, Static3Vector<T> v3) : m_rows{ v1, v2, v3 } {}
        Matrix3x3(T scalar) : m_rows{ Static3Vector(scalar, 0, 0), Static3Vector(0, scalar, 0), Static3Vector(0, 0, scalar) } {} //creates a scaled identity matrix
        ~Matrix3x3() = default;
private:                                
    Static3Vector<T> m_rows[3];
```

and the Static3Vector class

```
template <class T , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value, T>::type>
class Static3Vector
{
public:
    Static3Vector() : m_coords{ (T)0, (T)0, (T)0 } {}
    Static3Vector(T x, T y, T z) : m_coords{ x, y, z } {}
    Static3Vector(const Static3Vector& v) : m_coords{v[0], v[1], v[2]} {}
    ~Static3Vector() = default;
private:
    T m_coords[3];
```

The first project compiles just fine and outputs 0. The second projects throws

```
Error   C2955    'MathLib::Static3Vector': use of class template requires template argument list
```

What could be the cause for this? How to ensure that the library will work everytime?

Comment: Shouldn't `Static3Vector(scalar, 0, 0)` be `Static3Vector<T>(scalar, 0, 0)`?

Comment: @JoelFilho Well yes... and that actually fixed the error, but that wasn`t even the constructor that should be called in this case. And also why did the first project work in the first place, I made sure to use the same c++ version in both projects.

Comment: The error isn't on what constructor should be called, but actually just the declaration of the constructor with that call. So just having that code triggers the error. I added more details on the reasons for the error as an answer. But if it doesn't answer your question, just let me know, and I'll edit it.

Comment: Your anwser clears things up. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The C++17 standard introduces Class Template Argument Deduction (CTAD), which means:

```cpp
Static3Vector v(0, 0, 0);
```

Will compile on C++17, deducing `T=int`. On C++14, it will emit an error, as you must provide the type on the template. 
See this example side-by-side on Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/MHPkhh

So the solution for your case is either specify the template argument, force both build systems to use C++17, or use uniform initialization.

But if you're using the same compiler version for both cases and they're not yielding the same result, one of them might not be conforming to the Standard.